# How to check null reference before it throws an exception?

Tags: linq, nullreferenceexception

how to check this query if has any Item.

```
   Dim fls = (From fl In FSCHART.fltbars
                  Where fl.FLT_Value.FLIGHT_ID = local.LEG_Value.FLIGHT_ID
                  Select fl).First
```

in another case like:

```
   Dim fls = From fl In FSCHART.fltbars
                  Where fl.FLT_Value.FLIGHT_ID = local.LEG_Value.FLIGHT_ID
                  Select fl



for each row in fls
   textbox1.text=row.name
next
```

How to find out if a row is null before an exception error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first version, use `FirstOrDefault()`, not `First()`

then

```
If fls IsNot Nothing
```

For second version, use `Any()`

something like

```
If fls.Any()
```

But a for each on an empty Enumerable won't raise a Null reference exception...

Now, to avoid NRE in the query, use

```
Where fl.FLT_Valuefls IsNot Nothing AndAlso fl.FLT_Value.FLIGHT_ID = local.xxx
```

EDIT :

First check should be

```
If FSCHART.fltbars.Any()
```

Comment: Thank you for Fast answer. but firstordefault still says sequence has no element.NRF

Answer (score 0):

... where (something) != null.  E.g.

```
Where fl != null && 
    fl.FLT_Value != null && 
    fl.FLT_Value.FLIGHT_ID = local.LEG_Value.FLIGHT_ID
```